# passing multiple arguments to a gtk callback function

Tags: c, linux, gtk

I'm trying to pass multiple arguments to a gtk call back function
I have the following code so far:

```
void add_new_set(GtkDialog *dialog, gint response_id, gpointer callback_params)
{
  g_print (gtk_entry_get_text (((struct data *) callback_params)->entry));
}

struct data callback_params;
    callback_params.entry = gtk_entry_new();
    gtk_container_add(GTK_CONTAINER(content_area), callback_params.entry);
    g_signal_connect(dialog,"response",G_CALLBACK (add_new_set),&callback_params);
```

nothing get g_print ed
I get teh following error instead:
(tat:5918): Gtk-CRITICAL **: IA__gtk_entry_get_text: assertion 'GTK_IS_ENTRY (entry)' failed

(tat:5918): GLib-CRITICAL **: g_print: assertion 'format != NULL' failed

I'm open to using techniques other than passing a struct pointer

thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You practically need to pack the composite data in a *heap-allocated* `struct`, and pass the pointer to the callback.

```
struct data *cb_data = g_new0(struct data, 1);
cb_data->entry = gtk_entry_new();
cb_data->foo = "somefoo";
g_signal_connect(dialog,"response",G_CALLBACK (add_new_set), cb_data);
```

But you might instead have a single `static` variable of some `struct` type, and pass the address of that variable to your callback. This is usually bad practice and I don't recommend coding like this (since you want a callback to be somehow [reentrant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reentrancy_%28computing%29)).

You cannot take the address of a local variable and pass it to `g_signal_connect` (because GTK signal handling will use that pointer long after you have returned from your function so popped its [call frame](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Call_stack#CALL-FRAME)).

Of course, the issue is when should your program free that `cb_data`. Perhaps consider [g_signal_connect_data](https://developer.gnome.org/gobject/stable/gobject-Signals.html#g-signal-connect-data) which has a `destroy_data` closure notification. Or connect another signal to free that data (perhaps [widget "destroy"](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/GtkWidget.html#GtkWidget-destroy) or [dialog "close"](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/GtkDialog.html#GtkDialog-close) on your `dialog` ....).

You should consider using [valgrind](http://valgrind.org/) to debug [memory leaks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memory_leak).

Comment: perfect,
I used the static instead to allocate on the heap
I think it should be freed when the function returns(my functions returns after reading the config file as soon as the program runs)

I will definitely go through some valgrind tutorials to figure out if I have any memory leaks
I appreciate your answer, thank you very much